# Pull Text from a file based on if text is shown

Tags: vb.net, steam

I am trying in Visual Basic to find a certain ID in this Text shown below, then find out the "Path" that it is in:

Here is an example of the text:

```
"libraryfolders"
{
    "contentstatsid"        "-175455531451885641"
    "0"
    {
        "path"      "C:\\Program Files\\Steam"
        "label"     ""
        "contentid"     "-175455531451885641"
        "totalsize"     "0"
        "update_clean_bytes_tally"      "33093210635"
        "time_last_update_corruption"       "0"
        "apps"
        {
            "228980"        "542642082"
            "250820"        "5592394746"
            "378860"        "54160546915"
        }
    }
    "1"
    {
        "path"      "D:\\Program Files\\SteamLibrary"
        "label"     ""
        "contentid"     "324129293466563660"
        "totalsize"     "2000397791232"
        "update_clean_bytes_tally"      "30091152999"
        "time_last_update_corruption"       "0"
        "apps"
        {
            "8500"      "207310718"
        }
    }
```

I am trying to figure out how to find for example, 8500 and then look up to "path" to pull "D:\Program Files\SteamLibrary"

Or if I was to find 228980 - that would pull "C:\Program Files\Steam"

EDIT: I have very crudely figured a way out to do it.

```
Dim installPath As String = ""

        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1

            Dim curLine As String = objReader.ReadLine()

            If curLine.Contains("path") Then
                installPath = curLine
            End If

            If curLine.Contains("8500") Then
                installPath = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Mid(installPath, 12, 60)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Loop
```

Comment: This looks like malformed JSON. Is this exactly as you are receiving it?

Comment: Yes, this is the LibraryFolders.vdf that Steam generates - opened in notepad++ this is the format...